# How to configure the IIS to support WCF service?

Tags: wcf, iis

I wrote WCF service ( web service ). 
I never work with the IIS - and i dont know if i need to change \ config something in the IIS to work with my service.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

P.S: IIS version is 7.5

Comment: I don't recall ever having an issue deploying a WCF service to IIS. You should be able to create a new site or application in IIS and deploy your service to it without much additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting a service on an IIS Web server is very similar to hosting a traditional Web service (with an .asmx file extension).

Services hosted in IIS require the creation of a file with an .svc file extension. This is done for you automatically if you use the Visual Studio 2008/2010 WCF Service template. The Service.svc file is an XML-based file that must include an @ServiceHost directive.

```
<% @ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="EmployeeService" %>
```

in the web config you can leave the address attribute blank.

```
        <services>
            <service name="EmployeeService">
                <clear />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IEmployeeService" />
                <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttpBinding" contract="IEmployeeService" />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpBinding" contract="IEmployeeService" />
            </service>
        </services>
```

For more info take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx